# Adding a aar in eclipse

Tags: java, android, import, aar

i'm trying to add a aar file for the first time in my project :

http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

But i can't manage to make it work on eclipse, i tried to copy the aar file in my /libs than i do add to build path like i'm used to.

But my project can't import ffmeg. It is said in the documentation :

Or Maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg</groupId>
  <artifactId>FFmpegAndroid</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Where do i need to put this ? or this is the case you use Maven with android studio ? 
How can i import this aar?
Thank you very much

Comment: Eclipse with the ADT plugin does not natively support AAR files. If I understand correctly, the Maven plugin for Eclipse does. Or, you could try [converting the AAR into an Eclipse-style library project](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html).

Comment: Using Eclipse (ant) it is impossible, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211913/how-to-use-leakcanary-how-to-add-leakcanary-as-a-jar-to-build-a-apk-with-mk-fi. Using maven it is possible, but I didn't manage to make it work stable in Eclipse - it is not primary issue for android developers, so it is not surprising that it doesn't work without magic plugins (which were unstable in my case)